# vim-devicons not rendered properly

Tags: neovim, plugin-nerdtree, plugin-devicons

I am configuring [vim-devicons](https://github.com/ryanoasis/vim-devicons) for my neovim and this is my `init.nvim`:

```
:set number
:set autoindent
:set tabstop=4
:set shiftwidth=4
:set smarttab
:set softtabstop=4
:set mouse=a

call plug#begin()
Plug 'https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree' " NerdTree
Plug 'https://github.com/rafi/awesome-vim-colorschemes' " Retro Scheme
Plug 'https://github.com/ryanoasis/vim-devicons' " Developer Icons
call plug#end()

set encoding=UTF-8

:colorscheme molokayo

"let g:NERDTreeDirArrowExpandable="+"
"let g:NERDTreeDirArrowCollapsible="~"
```

but devicons are not rendered on my terminal at all (for hyper, gnome-terminal, terminator):

[image]

[image]

[image]

The font I use here is `Fira Code` but it doesn't work for `Cascadia` either.

I have also tried the [FAQ routine](https://github.com/ryanoasis/vim-devicons/wiki/FAQ-&-Troubleshooting#why-isnt-it-working-how-come-i-dont-see-any-icons) from vim-devicons:

1. `:echo loaded_webdevicons` returns 1
2. `:echo g:webdevicons_enable` returns 1
3. `:echo g:webdevicons_enable_nerdtree` returns 1
4. `:echo g:WebDevIconsUnicodeDecorateFileNodesDefaultSymbol` gives me an wrongly rendered symbol.

Now how do I fix it the get devicons working?

Comment: Do you still have the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to:

- Download and install the corresponding font from: [patched-fonts](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts#patched-fonts) for your platform
- Tell Neovim to use installed nerd font (e.g.: `:set guifont=FiraCode\ Nerd\ Font\ Mono:h9:cANSI`)
- Install and use the devicons plugin (`Plug 'ryanoasis/vim-devicons'` with [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug))